# Abuse of notation in the orbit stabilizer theorem proof

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

> The notation is the following: $G$ is a group acting on a set, $G_x = \{g \in G\mid gx = x \}$.  What does $G/G_x$ look like? [relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107590/my-proof-that-gx-to-g-g-x-is-injective?noredirect=1&lq=1)

In the above equation, is it an abusive of notation to write $G/G_x$ because $G_x$ is not neccesarily normal? If so what does it actually mean?

Comment: It's not a quotient group, because the stabilizer is almost never normal... it is a collection of left cosets. And for **any** group and subgroup $H$, the left cosets of $x$ and $y$ are equal if and only if $xH=yH$ as sets, if and only if $y^{-1}xH=H$ as sets, if and only if $y^{-1}x\in H$.

Comment: Two elements $g,h$ belong to the same coset of $G_x$ if and only if their action on $x$ is the same, i.e if $gx=hx$.

Comment: OK seems like I understood quotient groups totally wrong

Comment: It's **not** a quotient group! For the cosets to form a group under the operation $(xH)(yH)=(xy)H$ it is necessary and sufficient that $H$ be a normal subgroup. The stabilizer is not usually a normal subroup, so tnere is no "quotient group". Again, what you need to look at here are left cosets of a subgroup, *not* quotients.

Comment: You have opened my third eye. Is the question right now? @ArturoMagidin

Comment: What makes you think "the final biconditional [is] false"? No, the question still talks about quotients. For the third time, *there is no quotient*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $G$ is a group and $H$ its subgroup then

$$G/H:=\{ gH\ |\ g\in G\}$$

is the set of all (left) cosets of $H$ in $G$. This is a well defined set, regardless of whether $H$ is normal or not. Normality only gives us that this set together with $(gH, g'H)\mapsto gg'H$ operation is a well defined group, a.k.a. the quotient group. Nothing else.