# Understanding a classical theorem on commutator subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

I don't get the point when I see the theorem in the below figure. What does $G'\leq\ker\varphi$ want to tell (I know the mathematical meaning word by word, but don't know the intuitive meaning)? What does "factor through" mean? Only if I feel natural with it, then I can remember it.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *Homomorphism Lemma* states the following. Let $f\colon G\rightarrow H$ be a group homomorphism and $N$ be a normal subgroup of $G$ with
$$
N\subseteq \ker(f).
$$
Then there exists a unique group homomorphism $g:G/N\rightarrow H$ such that
$f=g\circ \pi$, where $\pi:G\rightarrow G/N$ is the canonical surjective homomorphism. Hence $f$ **factorizes** as $g\circ \pi$. We need the condition $N\subseteq \ker(f)$ in oder that $g$ is well-defined.

Comment: Dietrich Burde, would you say that $f$ factors through $N$ or through $G/N$? (This worried me about the statement in the OP's book).

Comment: @ancientmathematician Through $G/N$, yes. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/what-does-it-mean-to-say-a-map-factors-through-a-set).

Comment: My view, too. I think "buy a better book" is in order!

Comment: It's Dummit & Foote's *Abstract Algebra*. I'd heard many people complain about it, such as the organization or presentation. I rarely read this book.

Comment: I see! Thank you all! PS: I have never heard about homomorphism lemma before. And having known the meaning of factor through, I feel more natural about this theorem.

Comment: @Eric I’d recommend Aluffi’s *Algebra: Chapter 0*. Given some of the other questions you’ve asked on this site, that book might be helpful.

Comment: @SantanaAfton Thanks. I'll definitely check this!