# Showing given map is a ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

I was trying some examples on ring homomorphisms. Got stuck in an intermediate step in which I have to show that:

A map $f$: $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$ $\rightarrow$ $\Bbb{Z}_{20}$ defined as $f(x)$ = $\bar {16}x$ is a ring homomorphism.

Please help!

Comment: One thing that you have to be careful about is making sure that $f$ is well defined. First, define $g: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_{20}$ by $g(x) = 16x$. Check that $g(a+b) = g(a) + g(b)$ and $g(ab) = g(a)g(b)$. This will show that $g$ is a ring homomorphism. Next, check to make sure that $10\mathbb{Z} \subset \ker g$. This amounts to showing that $g(10x) = 0$. By the first isomorphism theorem, $g$ factors through $\mathbb{Z}_10$. That is, the map $f$ is indeed a ring homomorphism.

Comment: What do you mean by g factors through $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$..how to use the first isomorphism theorem..Since you didn't find the kernel..you have just shown that 10Z is contained in kernel of g.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/what-does-it-mean-to-say-a-map-factors-through-a-set.

Comment: what is $16^-$?

Comment: @CharlieChang I think $\bar {16}$ refers to the equivalence class represented by $16$

Comment: Hey how can we verify that g is a ring homomorphism?

Comment: @ Mike..Also by using that theorem, we get that g = fk where k will be canonical projection..How to find f from here?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

Recall ring homs $f : \mathbb{Z}/(n) \to R$ are in bijective correspondence with ring homs $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{Z} \to R$ with the bonus property that $\tilde{f}(n) = 0$. This is sometimes called a [Universal Property](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Universal_Property_of_Quotient_Ring), and if your book didn't prove it, it's a good exercise to do yourself.

In light of this fact, to show that $f$ is a ring hom, it suffices to show that the map $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/(20)$ which is defined by the same formula ($\tilde{f}(x) = \overline{16}\overline{x}$) is a ring hom with $\tilde{f}(10) = 0$.

Is this problem more approachable? If not, notice $\tilde{f}$ is really a composite of two functions: first we have $\pi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/(20)$ the natural quotient map (i.e. $\pi(x) = \overline{x}$). Then we have $m : \mathbb{Z}/(20) \to \mathbb{Z}/(20)$ with $m(\overline{x}) = \overline{16} \overline{x}$.

Can you show that $\pi$ and $m$ are both ring homs? Then, since the composition of ring homs is a ring hom, you will have that $\tilde{f} = m \circ \pi$ is a ring hom too, as needed.

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: Here n means ideal generated by n..right?

Comment: yes! Sorry, I should have been more clear with that

Comment: I've added in the parenthesis, which is the standard notation for "ideal generated by". Life is too short to do this all the time, but it's important to be clear when starting out ^_^

Comment: It's okay..how can f be a ring homomorphism on both Z/<n> and Z?

Comment: It's the same formula, so it is a standard "abuse of notation" to use the same symbol for both. Technically, though, they are different functions. If you'd like, I can edit the question to make this more clear

Comment: Yes..please do that

Comment: I am not sure if I will be able to show that m is a ring homomorphism

Comment: As another hint: showing that will make critical use of the fact that $16^2 = 16$ mod $20$. If you're having more specific issues showing that, I suggest you ask a new question so we can move this discussion out of the comments

Comment: Okay...Thanks for the effort:)