# Show orbit map $g\to g\cdot x$ factors through well-defined bijective map as defined below

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions

I am given a group $G$ acting on $X$. Let $x$ be any element of $X$. Denote by $G\cdot x$ its orbit and $G_x$ its isotropy. I need to show orbit map $g\mapsto g\cdot x$ factors through the well defined bijective $G/G_x \to G\cdot x$  that maps $gG_x\to g\cdot x$, to define the following $G$- equivariant commutative diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
G\\
@VVV @.\\
G/G_x @>>> G\cdot x 
\end{CD}
I am familiar with the notations of orbits and isotropy but I don't really know how will i be defining the elements of these groups to prove that it factors that way? Any hints?

Comment: Do you know it is well-defined and bijective? Then the key is showing the map factors that way.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It is quite easy to show there is a one to one correspondence but after that, showing the map factors that way is giving a bit trouble here ? I don't get it how will I show that? what does it mean to factor in this case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the map $\varphi\colon G\to G\cdot x$ to *factor through* $\overline\varphi\colon G/G_x\to G\cdot x$ means that there exists a map $\pi\colon G\to G/G_x$ *factoring* $\varphi$; that simply means $\varphi$ can be written as $\varphi=\overline\varphi\circ\pi$.

So what you have to do is finding the map $\pi$, for which there is an obvious canidate, and verify the equation $\varphi=\overline\varphi\circ\pi$ for your chosen map. Then the next step is verifing $G$-equivariance. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes, I think i  can take it from here.

Comment: @HaneenHussam Glad to help!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/21932/what-does-it-mean-to-say-a-map-factors-through-a-set

Comment: This is incomplete you need to show phi is well defined

Comment: @Buraian I'm not sure what you mean? As I don't give a complete such details are naturally left to the reader.